# Partial initialization for an array of structures in C

Tags: c, struct, initialization

While revising my C knowledge, I stumbled into the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Just a simple structure */
typedef struct lab {
    int num;
    char *str;
} bal;

int main (void) {
    /* Declare and _partially_ initialize an array of the structure above... */
    bal struct_array[10] = { {0, NULL} };

    /* Question: what does _exacly_ happen to the other 9 members of the array? */ 
    return 0;
};
```

The comment in the code should be enough to provide my question. In other words, what does it happen if we partially initialize an array of structs? Sure, I know that (at least) for C++11 there is the default initialization. But does it hold for pure C, too? If yes, is it true for all the standards (from C89 on), or just for some in particular? Thank you.

Comment: I think you could even achieve the same result with just `bal struct_array[10] = {{0}};`

Comment: Yes, now that we know the default initialization to hold, I certainly agree on '={{0}}'; and the other proposed variants.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 `= {0};` will also work as a "universal initializer".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If an array or struct is only partially initialized, any containing objects without an explicit initializer are set to 0 or NULL.

Partial initialization is covered in section 6.7.9p21 of the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size  than  there  are  elements  in  the  array,  the  remainder  of  the  aggregate  shall  be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

And initialization of objects with static storage duration are covered in section 6.7.9p10:

> If  an  object  that  has  automatic  storage  duration  is  not
> initialized  explicitly,  its  value  is indeterminate.   If  an
> object  that  has  static  or  thread  storage  duration  is  not
> initialized explicitly, then:
>
> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized
>   to zero bits

So in your particular case, all array elements will have the `num` member set to 0 and the `str` member set to NULL.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the reference. Does it also hold for C89 and C99?

Comment: @user47 Yes, there is similar language in C89 and C99.