# Why my table is not displayed if I do not put it [i]

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I would like to know what the `[i]` is for, and why my table is not displayed if I do not put it in.
Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void affiche(int* tableau, int taille);

int main()
{
    int tableau[5] = { 12,15,50,20 };

    affiche(tableau, 4);

    return 0;
}

void affiche(int *tableau,int taille)

{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < taille; i++)`
    {
        printf("%d\n", tableau[i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You must be just starting to learn C, or you wouldn't need to ask this question. Do you know any other programming languages already? If so, which ones?  What books on C have you read?  Are you working through some sort of course? (Which one?) Finally, what did you _expect_ `printf("%d\n", tableau)` to do?

Comment: Paste the text, [not an image of the text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). `tableau` is a pointer-to-int. `a[i]` is a shortcut to `*(a+i)`, it dereferences `*(tableau + i)`.

Comment: @zwol yes I'm a beginner and I know a little java and python but I'm more on c and I'm learning about to openclassrooms, and I was expect to display my table, sorry for english i'm a french..

Comment: @Neil oh okey sry i just arrived on stack overflow, i do not understand everything

Comment: Beinvenu à StackOverflow! Les pointes sont arbitaire, mais une post avec une image de code est un façon de garnir les downvotes. Malhuresement, les edits que vous avez faits ne parfois pas atteint les downvoters. (Mais c'est bénèfique quand meme.)

Comment: As to why you didn't get the expected output, a [pointer-to-int tableau](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*tableau) does not match with `%d`, so your programme is not well-defined in that case. See https://c-faq.com/varargs/index.html.

Comment: @Neil ok thx for you help, i'm going to see this link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[i]` is the C language syntax for array notation.

`tableau` is an array of 5 integers.

```
int tableau[5] = {12,15,50,20}
```

In memory tableau has 5 slots allocated to it due to the above declaration.

Slots 0 through 3 are your initialization values.
Slot 4 is uninitialized (though modern c compilers *might* set this value to null or zero (0).

```
      tableau
      +-----------------------+
index | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4 |
      +-----------------------+
value | 12 | 15 | 50 | 20 | ? |
      +-----------------------+
```

inside function `affiche(...)` this statement

```
printf("%d\n", tableau)
```

tries to print to console a single integer (%d) followed by a newline (\n)

But `tableau` is an array of 5 integers.

So you need the array index to select a specific integer individually like this:

```
printf("%d\n", tableau[0])  // output: 12
printf("%d\n", tableau[1])  // output: 15
printf("%d\n", tableau[2])  // output: 50
printf("%d\n", tableau[3])  // output: 20
printf("%d\n", tableau[4])  // output: unknown, possible exception
```

or by function call to `affiche(tableau, 4);` which ends at index 3

```
void affiche( int *tableau, int taille)
{
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < taille; i++){
        printf( "%d\n", tableau[i] );
    }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
12
15
50
20
```

Comment: Yes, that is guaranteed by all standard C dialects. See [partial initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67506436/2472827).